# Can React animate a component being hidden/removed?

Tags: reactjs

I know that using `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` you can apply it to a list of items and have then animate as they appear or disappear. What about a single component though?

See JSFiddle here, where I've got a CSS animation when the item appears. But I don't know if there's a way to make it animate upon being hidden.

https://jsfiddle.net/eq263rk2/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Sure! Just use the `enter` and `leave` variants (though you should always render the `TransitionGroup` component):

```javascript
var TheThing = React.createClass({
    render() {
        var component;
        if (this.props.visible) {
            component = <div className="the-thing">The Thing</div>;
        }

        return (
            <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="thing">
                {component}
            </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
        )
    }
});
```

and

```css
.thing-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
}

.thing-enter.thing-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.thing-leave {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
}

.thing-leave.thing-leave-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/3fkso0kq/

Comment: Ah! I was under the impression `enter`/`leave` was for a list of items, and `appear` was for a single item. What's the point of `appear` then and how dose it differ?

Comment: @ffxsam `appear` is for the initial appearance of the item, if you use `transitionAppear` — that is to say, if the `TransitionGroup` and it's children are *already mounted* when the containing component mounts, it won't animate unless `transitionAppear` is set. Try setting `{thingIsVisible: true}` in your example, and then in mine.